# String replacement in PHP

Tags: php, regex, string

This is my first question on this wonderful website.

Lets say I have a string `$a="some text..%PROD% more text"` There will be just one `%..%` in the string. I need to replace `PROD` between the `%` with another variable content. So I used to do:

```
$a = str_replace('%PROD%',$var,$a);
```

but now the `PROD` between `%` started coming in different cases. So I could expect prod or Prod. So I made the entire string uppercase before doing replacement. But the side effect is that other letters in the original string also became uppercase. Someone suggested me to use regular expression. But how ?

Thanks,

Rohan

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can make use of [str_ireplace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php) function. Its similar to [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) but is case insensitive during matching.

```
$x = 'xxx';
$str = 'abc %Prod% def';
$str = str_ireplace('%PROD%',$x,$str); // $str is now "abc xxx def"
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use [`str_ireplace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php). It's a case-insensitive version of `str_replace()`, and much more efficient for a simple replacement than regular expressions (also much more straightforward).

Answer (score 3):

You could use a regular expression, but PHP also conveniently has a case-insensitive version of `str_replace`, [`str_ireplace`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php)